# JQuery pass HTML ID as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, element

Here is my code:

HTML

> ```
> <img src"../MyPic_1" id="MyImg_1" onclick = "MyJQfunction($(this))">
> <img src"../MyPic_2" id="MyImg_2" onclick = "MyJQfunction($(this))">
> <img src"../MyPic_3" id="MyImg_3" onclick = "MyJQfunction($(this))">
> ```

JQUERY

> ```
> <script>
> function MyJQfunction(MyField)
> {
>   MyField.hide();
> }
> </script>
> ```

As you can see I'm trying to send the HTML element to my JQ Function so it knows what to hide.

**What am I doing wrong?**

NOTE: This is just a simple example of what I really need to do, I just want to avoid including codes that you don't care about. Thanks!

Comment: What you have works, once you fix the syntax error. http://jsfiddle.net/3ynDC/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a typo.

Comment: The typo is not the problem, it was a mistake of mine when writing the question. As I said at the note: This is just an example.

Comment: Right, but it's the ONLY problem with the code you have presented. you actual error must be in the code you considered unimportant.

Comment: OMG !! I just copy-pasted my example code to a single html file and it really works (fixing the typo of course).

You're right Kevin, my mistake must be somewhere else. THANX !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
<img src="../MyPic_1" id="MyImg_1" class="image_to_hide"/>
<img src="../MyPic_2" id="MyImg_2" class="image_to_hide"/>
<img src="../MyPic_3" id="MyImg_3" class="image_to_hide"/>
```

...

```
<script>
    $(".image_to_hide").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is very efficient since it's so simple, but my code is a bit more complicated and it doesn't fit. But thanx, I'm sure your answer will be used by others.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jquery so attach an event handler instead of using `onclick`

```
<img src="../MyPic_1" id="MyImg_1" class="myIMage">
<img src="../MyPic_2" id="MyImg_2" class="myIMage">
<img src="../MyPic_3" id="MyImg_3" class="myIMage">
```

and

```
$(function(){
      $('.myIMage').on('click', MyJQFunction);
 }

function MyJQFunction()
{
   $(this).hide(); //here this represents the element clicked.
}
```

Or classic way; use [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context for the function while invocation.

```
<img src"../MyPic_1" id="MyImg_1" onclick = "MyJQfunction.call(this)">
```

and

```
function MyJQFunction()
{
   $(this).hide(); //and this here is now the clicked element.
}
```

Also in your code your image tag seems to be incorrect and `MyJQfunction` versus `MyJQFunction` has casing (note the casing of `f`) issue. Check your console for errors. Otherwise your code should work.

Comment: Great, I tried both ways and they work perfect !!

Just a note for others:

At the second option, if you have more parameters:

**HTML**
<img src"../MyPic_1" id="MyImg_1" onclick = "MyJQfunction.call(this, 2ndPar, 3rdPar)">

**JQUERY**
function MyJQFunction(2ndPar, 3rdPar)  **// no need to declare a parameter for 'this'**

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap that on jquery function like this

```
function MyJQFunction(MyField)
{
  $(MyField).hide();
}
```